# Java - spring @IntegrationTest always on 8080

Tags: java, spring, web, spring-boot

I'm trying to run an integration test on a random port using Spring annotation `@IntegrationTest`. However, I'm getting 8080 all the time. Any ideas?

The code I' using:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener;
import com.github.springtestdbunit.annotation.DatabaseSetup;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {FooConfig.class})
@DatabaseSetup("/db/Foo.xml")
@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")
@Transactional
public class Foo{

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(port);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `@TestExecutionListeners` overrides similar config on the `@IntegrationTest` (see its source code). Hence it eliminates `IntegrationTestPropertiesListener`. Can you somehow overcome your `DbUnitTestExecutionListener` to avoid `@TestExecutionListeners` ?

Comment: @Artem Bilan Thanks, we overrided the configuration using application.properties file.